# Why use N-channel and P-channel MOSFETS with an ESC instead of just using N-ch MOSFETS?

Tags: mosfet, motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I am following [this build](https://www.instructables.com/Make-Your-Own-Sensored-ESC/) for an ESC.

I don't understand why this build uses both n-channel and p-channel MOSFETS instead of just using N-channel MOSFETS because they are less expensive and easier to find.

Why go through the trouble of inverting the signal with a 74HC14 and then applying it to the gate p-channel MOSFET instead of just directly applying it to the gate N-channel MOSFET instead?

What's the advantage of doing this?

Comment: Simpler gate drive, can work down to very low frequencies without running out of bootstrap voltage. This is often offset by higher cost for a given RdsON so it’s not common.

Comment: Do you know what floating gate drive is? You need that if you use high-side NMOS. That's the disadvantage and it is not an insignificant aspect for designs that are very small or low power. For any significant power level though you probably would just use NMOS.

Comment: because an nchan's source pin has to be at least a few volts less than the gate pin's voltage. when you use that on the low side, the source is 0v, no problem with logic-level gate control. If you did the same high-side, you would only provide a few volts (or less) to the motor (vgs(your circuit) - vgs(th)). If the motor is driven at 24v, then you would have to provide 27v+ to the gate of a high-side nchan to get a full turn-on, and that's a lot more complicated than just using a pchan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several things:

1. As winny commented, it can be easier to do.  And at low-ish power levels and low frequencies (a motor's going to run max ~kHz?), the poorer performance of PMOS isn't so significant.
2. Bootstrap NMOS drivers are fine, but they do have a power requirement: either periodically refreshing (low side turns on, recharging the bootstrap capacitor), or with a charge pump or isolated supply (which allows static (down to DC) operation).  Hence the frequency limitation.  For a motor, maybe this wouldn't be a problem, but then again maybe it would.  (If the high side doesn't have sufficient voltage, it simply doesn't turn on at all -- possible result, a motor that never spins.)
3. The circuit is faulty.  I have seen very few actually-good designs on Instructables, in general, and this appears to be no exception.  It's almost as if it's made to fail, which seems to clash with the claim that it "works" later on.  The problem is this: the TC4427 gate driver outputs a 0/15V level.  The 15V supply is derived from a 7815 regulator, which drops about 2V minimum, and more when VCC > 17V.  The PMOS senses a voltage between gate and source, and when gate is less than Vgs(th) below source, it's on.  This is typically 2V or so.  So already we see it's impossible for the PMOS to fully turn off, basically ever.  This is only worsened at higher VCC (say 24V, where the PMOS is always turned fully on!).  Most likely the transistors destroy themselves; hopefully the user has fused the supply, or used a current limited supply, to limit damage here.

There's also the issue that, when the gate driver itself is disabled (low supply voltage, or when disabled for certain types), the output pulls to zero, forcing the PMOS on once again.

There are very few PMOS-specific gate drivers out there; at the point you need them, you're better off using a bootstrap or other type NMOS driver and reaping the performance benefits.

The best case for complementary power transistors is at low voltages, where gate drive can be taken directly from logic pin outputs -- 74HC/LVC for example, or an MCU or controller ASIC.  The same supply is used for logic and motor supply (say 3.3 or 5V), and so there's no issue with insufficient or indeterminate gate voltages.  These are of course quite low power levels, like you'd have in a hard drive spindle motor say, not for real motive power like a bicycle.